# Information about appeals againt the patent

Tags: us7370285

In reference to the patent: [US7370285](https://www.google.com/patents/US7370285)

Please refer this article 
http://www.law360.com/articles/683721?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=articles_search 
which states that above patent is declared invalid for being obvious by Patent Appealate Board. Can this information be not incorporated while displaying information about Patent ?

Comment: Sure it can be incorporated, but this is off-topic here. The suggestion belongs with google.